# Using 6/3 NM cable to feed 60 Amp to subpanel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

EDIT: Nobody was willing to answer cable needed for 100 amp feeder so removed questions. Also, code references in the answer are several years or more out of date...

Ed B was correct to be careful of the "internet electricians" on this site.

Comment: You could put a 200 amp panel in with a 200 amp main it is just considered a disconnect.  your feeder wire has to be protected by the breaker in the main sizes under #1 / 100 amps need the 60 degree table so the 50 amp breaker is the appropriate size. A very similar question is on my states “master” exam choose 60 A breaker and it will be wrong no matter how many internet electricians say the 75 degree is ok. There are safety’s built into the code and this is one.

Comment: Code actually states #1  and normally copper is what code is referring to unless the type is identified, I did hear a friend argue the code is not clear and the inspector signed off on #1 at the higher amperage my state is usually quite strict on residential for feeders because many DIY try fudged get the numbers.

Comment: Congrats on going _BIG_ on that new sub-panel! It avoids everyone telling you to do so. ;)

Comment: #1 aluminum can use the 75 degree table and is rated for 100 amps I am not sure where you are getting your derating from.  if you want to use 1/0 that will allow your feeder breaker to be up to 120 amp.

Comment: Most Americans live in states still on NEC 2014 or 2017. Since you seem dissatisfied with the 1 answer, and are trying to delete this question, then I suggest you UN-acccept my answer and write a comment back to me.   Once you do so, I can delete my answer.  Once I do so, you can delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 100A feeder, use #1 aluminum.  For 90A feeder, use the more popular #2 aluminum. Don't even bother with copper at these sizes.   4-wire #2Al is $1.40/foot.

### Insulation doesn't derate all wires, only SE cable.  *And only on Tuesdays during the full moon.*

The question of whether SE cable is good for 60C or 75C thermal was settled for 40 years... it was 75C thermal.   And then, some wire salesman proposed a change to NEC to reduce it to  60C, same as NM cable, which is itself a weird exception.  (We're talking when SE cable is used in feeder or branch circuit wiring the way NM would be).  Everyone else missed it, so nobody gave any feedback to the contrary, so the NEC committee just rubber-stamped it and it got into a Code edition.

*Oh boy, and that kicked over the hive*.  The feedback came fast and furious, "why'd you break it, there hasn't been a reportable problem in 40 years".  So it was mostly changed back.  Anyway, the rule has changed a little every Code edition since, particularly the part about whether insulation matters.  You have to go pull your current code and read carefully.

### Or, just don't use SE cable

THHN or XHHW in smurf tube will work just fine.   Anything that isn't NM, UF or (sometimes) SE is good for 75C.

A lot of wires are good for 90C, the problem is, the terminals aren't.

Once you have your metal and temperature, you pull your ampacity out of Table 310.15(B)(16).

### If reusing the 6/3NM, you get 55A.

Because NM cable is limited by NEC 334.80 to the 60C column in the ampacity chart.

That means you can't *plan to* use more than 55A.  I.E when you do your load calculation on the subpanel, it can't exceed 55A. If it does you'll have to remove loads.

As far as what circuit breaker to feed that with, they don't make 55A breakers. NEC allows you to round up to the next available breaker size, 60A.   *However the panel's load calc can only be 55A*.

Here's an example.  You get a tankless water heater that draws 56A.  56A is greater than 55A, so you cannot use #6 NM cable for that, even though it's breakered at 60A.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact They're generally not counted as continuous loads.

Comment: Which means that tankless water heaters are not UL-tested with teenagers.

Comment: @manassehkatz Or for that matter, multi-female houses, noting the allowance of any number of bathrooms to share the same receptacle circuit.